# Cakephp Media Plugin Problem

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to use the Media Plugin (http://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp-media)

I placed the media folder contents in app/plugins/media

then in bootstrap.php in the app/config/ folder added the following code.

```
Configure::load('media.core');
```

Now when i run any controller and any action am getting the following error.

```
Configure::load() - no variable $config found in core.php [CORE\cake\libs\configure.php, line 266]
```

I am using Cakephp 1.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loading config files with cakes Configure::load() has a requirement that the configs be in a variable called $config

eg

```
<?php 
$config['Meh'] = array('foo' => 'bar');
?>
```